# How to send commands to gps tracker with php

Tags: php, tcp, gps, udp

I'm trying to develop php based tracking software for my gps tracker gps107.

My tracker has GPRS and I have successfully associated my tracker with open source tracking software "Traccar" which is written in java and located in my server.

But now I want to develop my own custom software for my needs in php.

I also have the protocol manual where I can see available commands and their responses.

example command for locating:

server -> device

```
**,imei:359586018966098,100
```

device -> server `imei:353451044508750,001,0809231929,,F,055403.000,A,2233.1870,N,11354.3067,E,0.00,,;`

How can I send these commands with php ?

Comment: Although I'm not positive, I believe you want to send using UDP

Comment: That may be the case because the tracker supports tcp and udp.

Comment: @MulOnPomm were you able to achieve this? I also want the same thing.

Comment: Look my added answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The communication between server and a device is made with UDP or TCP protocol. To make this type of a connection with PHP  you have to create PHP socket server. Then  you assign server IP and port to  your device, and the device will connect to the server as a client. After that you can receive and send commands.

PHP Doumentation about sockets: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php
Excample socket server: http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php/